# ReCaptcha works on dev and QA but not production

Tags: .net, recaptcha

Keys were generated for Recaptcha using the a domain similar to www.abc.com. Our development and QA environments are setup using dev.abc.com and qa.abc.com.

The Recaptcha code works on dev and QA but fails everytime on production. We are using the same set of keys on each environment. We've checked the keys and everything else on production to make sure that everything is copacetic.

The production environment has 3 servers behind a load balancer which routes traffic to the web servers using two internal IPs. That's the only difference architecture-wise between production and QA.

When I try to hit the service using Postman REST client, I consistently get the following error - false invalid-request-cookie.

I know that this error can come up due to wrong "challenge" parameter in the request. How can I resolve this problem? Are there some sample values that I can use to check the ReCaptcha on production?

Thanks

Comment: This is the first time I've seen the word `copacetic` :O

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your key as global...
Enable this key on all domains (global key).

https://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: Yes they key was setup as global.